# How to pass list's values one by one in another predicate prolog

Tags: prolog

This is my prologdb file

```
trip_to_nation(X,Y,T):- % X is a city ,T is a list
      list_airport(Y,A),
      write(A),% [dublin,cork] list 
      all_trip(X,A,T). % here A is an atom and T is the list
```

I want to pass the list's value  one by one to the all_trip such to get the data ,how it is possible?

Something like `list[0],list[1]` and get the data in the list .Thanks

Comment: You need to clarify what the predicates `list_airport` and `all_trip` are doing.

Comment: updated ,@DavidTonhofer

Comment: This may help: [`member/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member/2) will backtrack over list contents. Direct access-by-indexing is done (inefficiently) with [`nth0/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth0/3).

Comment: I tried its not working `all_trip(X,member(One, [One]),T).` @DavidTonhofer

Comment: I see: `maplist(all_trip(X,A), Ts).` will call `all_trip(X,A,T)` for every `T` in List `Ts`. See [`maplist/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/2)

Comment: Can you please show all of your code? Right now this fails at `list_airport/2`. We can't help you with this limited amount of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now T will have all the trips from X to elements of A.

```
maplist(all_trip(X), A, T).
```

If you want the trips as multiple solutions rather a list of them all, the following will work.

```
member(City, A), all_trip(X, City, T).
```

Comment: but how to pass that in all_trip()?

Comment: What exactly is `all_trip` doing? Can you share that code?

Comment: /**
 * All the trips between two cities 
 *
 * find all trips between C (first city) and L(second city)  and put then in T
 */

 all_trip(C,L,T):-
      findall(Ci, trip(C,L,any,Ci), T).

Comment: all_trip gives a list of all the trips between two cities C and L

Comment: @gANDALF : I am not sure of the rest of the code but my update answer should suffice this particular question.

Comment: Yeah its working ,can I show it one by one ? instead of a list